# Whats the fastest way to write a journal to an SSD in Java?

Tags: java, performance, solid-state-drive, ext4

I have small transactions which I need to sync to the filesystem (ext4) onto a SSD within a java program.

What is the fastest way to write these transactions sequencial into a file, if I need to sync with the filesystem after each transaction?
The data per transaction is realy small, but it would be ok to write more (to fill a page for example), if that increases transactions/s.

After the data was written once, it is only read.

Also, are there any tweaks to the filesystem that increase the performance?
Is there a stable filesystem that is suited better for that task?

**UPDATE:** This seems to be a filesystem problem. Ext4 is much slower than Ext3, when using sync?
Suggestion?
**UPDATE** The solution to the problem is, preallocation the file (in java _file.setLength(size) ). This will cause on ext4 that the space is preallocated and all metadata is writen once. After this, writeing to the file will only edit the user data and metadata is keeped unchanged.
This causeed a speedup by factor 10 in my case.

Comment: read up on some of the design patterns employed my sqlalchemy. It is python thing but I think you will find the docs useful anyway.

Comment: Do you have a link to the paterns?

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Journal.IO](https://github.com/sbtourist/Journal.IO)?

> Journal.IO is a zero-dependency, fast and easy-to-use journal storage implementation based on append-only rotating logs and checksummed variable-length records, supporting concurrent reads and writes, dynamic batching, tunable durability and data compaction.